# Delete and Add UITableView Row

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

In my application, I have a UITableView that I specify in `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` to have 150 rows. Now, my data source NSArray has more than 150 elements, so, as expected, my table displays the first 150. I have also implemented `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` so that the user can delete elements from the UITableView. What I want to happen, when a user has deleted a row, is for the deleted row to disappear (with animation), then have the rest of the rows slide up, and the 151st element of the data source array, which was previously not displayed, to be show as the last element of the table. However, everything I have tried so far has given me the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (150) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (150), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
First throw call stack:
(0x2e58fecb 0x38d2ace7 0x2e58fd9d 0x2ef3de2f 0x30f94761 0x30ff0f7f 0x2af0f49 0xdf763 0x30fba567 0x30fba4f9 0x30df66a7 0x30df6643 0x30df6613 0x30de1d5b 0x30df605b 0x30db9521 0x30df1305 0x30df0c2b 0x30dc5e55 0x30dc4521 0x2e55afaf 0x2e55a477 0x2e558c67 0x2e4c3729 0x2e4c350b 0x334326d3 0x30e24871 0x106b59 0x39228ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

The following code explains the gist of how I am trying to implement this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        PNObject *objectToDelete = contentArray[indexPath.row];
        NSMutableArray *mutableCopy = [contentArray mutableCopy];
        [mutableCopy removeObject:objectToDelete];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if still relevant mate,
But What I think is happening is that you don't actually update your data source.

You are creating a 'local' mutable copy of your data source, and removing the object in that copy, but your actual data source is remains the same, and still contain the item that you are removing.

I'm guessing that your `numberOfRows:inSection:` contains some variation of `[contentArray count]`

So what happening is that you are 'removing' an item from the table view, so your app excepts that table view to have one less item,
But when reloading the table view's content, since the item wasn't removed from the data source, the table view have one more item than it expects.

To resolve that, change contentArray to NSMutableArray,
And in your above code, remove `objectToDelete` directly from there.
Then you could also remove the object directly from the array, without creating a local reference to it.
So your above code should look like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {  

        [contentArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Already fixed the issue, but I'll give ya the answer anyways. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I figured there is a chance you already found a solution to this by now. Thank you for marking it as an answer anyway.